# What a strange syntax?

Tags: javascript

I've found unknown for me code construction on JQuery site. After some formatting it looks like:

```
function (a,c) {
    c==null && (c=a,a=null);
    return arguments.length>0
        ? this.bind(b,a,c) 
        : this.trigger(b)
}
```

What does the first line of the function mean? Is it any trick or standard JS code construction?

Comment: it's a standard in Java, php, Javascript and about any other language

Comment: If you're going to look at the jQuery code, look at the development copy and not the minified one. **[Here's a link](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js)** to the development copy.

Comment: @Tom: the [comma operator](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.14) is different in JavaScript that in other  languages with a C-inspired syntax.

Comment: Wow, those code minifiers are aggressive - it's only one character shorter than `if(c==null){c=a;a=null}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a trick that uses boolean short-circuit evaluation to only do the second half if the first evaluates to true. Perl has this commonly:

```
<something> or die
```

where if the first statement failed, the program ends.

Read it as

```
if (c == null) { c = a; a = null; }
```

Comment: The comma makes both commands execute without need of a semicolon.

Comment: which in turn allows *both* statements to execute in a **single line**, which is a character savings over an if-statement.

Comment: @Gunslinger_ : how much faster actually?

Comment: Python also allows you to use `A or B` as an equivalent to something like `A != null && A == true ? A : B`. Though in Python you'd say that as `A if A != None and A == True else B`. I might be missing some of the subtleties of Python's usage, though.

Comment: @JAB that is possible in javascript

Answer (score 12):

That's an ugly way to write

```
if(c==null) {
  c = a;
  a = null;
}
```

This utilizes the fact, that the second part of boolean `&&` will be executed if, and only if the first part evaluates to true.

Comment: Very ugly. And very unintuitive to many developers. Can you find the person who wrote it and kick them.

Comment: @Schroedingers Cat: as variables are named `a`, `b`, `c` this code has probably been generated by a code minifier. [jQuery currently seems](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/Makefile#L8) to use [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS).

Comment: Uglify? That explains a lot, doesn't it? ;D

Answer (score 2):

The expression uses two JavaScript features :

- *short circuit evaluation* of boolean operators: in [statement context](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12), `a && (b);` is equivalent to `if (a) (b);`
- *[the comma operator](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.14)* to group assignment expressions: in [statement context](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12), `a=b,b=c;` is equivalent to `{ a=b; b=c }`

As a result the expression is equivalent to:

```
if (c == null) {
    c = a
    a = null
}
```