# How to recursively delete a field from an object in javascript ignoring optional fields

Tags: javascript

I have a an Object and I need to delete all the "id" attributes inside at every deep level except for some of them.

I did this function:

```
const removeFieldFromObject = ({ obj, fieldName, ignoreFields = [] }) => {
  if (typeof obj !== "object" || obj === null) {
    return obj;
  }

  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      obj[i] = removeFieldFromObject({ obj: obj[i], fieldName, ignoreFields });
    }
  } else {
    for (var prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if (prop === fieldName && !ignoreFields.includes(obj[prop])) {
          delete obj[prop];
        } else {
          obj[prop] = removeFieldFromObject({
            obj: obj[prop],
            fieldName,
            ignoreFields,
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
};
```

If i invoke it with this object in the following way:

```
const obj = {
  id:1,
  data:{
    id:2,
    cards:{
      id:123,
      name:"my name",
      document:{
        id:2,
        url:"my url"
      }
    }
  }
}

const formattedObj = removeFieldFromObject({obj, fieldName: "id", ignoreFields: ["document"]})
```

It deletes the "id" attribute at all levels

I want it do remove all the attributes "id" except for document objects. This method removes them at every level. The reason is the condition on `ignoreFields` that is always true when it goes inside the `document` object and it checks the actual props. I [looked around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67786096/remove-recursively-a-key-from-object-in-javascript) and found many similar questions but not with optional attributes.

Do you have any suggestion? I accept also solutions with lodash or similar.

Comment: `I need to delete all the "id" attributes` can't you just ignore them if you don't need them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if (prop === fieldName && !ignoreFields.includes(obj[prop])) {
>   delete obj[prop];
> } else {
>   obj[prop] = removeFieldFromObject(…);
> }
> ```

This doesn't make a lot of sense - or at least, it doesn't match how you are calling the function. It checks for the *value* of the property to delete in the `ignoreFields`. What you actually want is to check the property *name* before doing the recursive call, so that nothing in `.document` does get visited:

```
if (prop === fieldName) {
  delete obj[prop];
} else if (!ignoreFields.includes(prop)) {
  obj[prop] = removeFieldFromObject(…);
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Could be something like this:

```js
const removeFieldFromObject = ({obj, fieldName, ignoreFields}) => {

  if(Array.isArray(obj)) {
    arr.forEach(item => removeFieldsFromObject({obj, fieldName, ignoreFields}));
    return;
  }
  if(!Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj)){
    return;
  }
  delete obj[fieldName];
  
  for(const k in obj){
    ignoreFields.includes(k) || removeFieldFromObject({obj: obj[k], fieldName, ignoreFields});
  }
};

removeFieldFromObject({obj, fieldName: "id", ignoreFields: ["document"]})

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script>
const obj = {
  id:1,
  data:{
    id:2,
    cards:{
      id:123,
      name:"my name",
      document:{
        id:2,
        url:"my url"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Better avoid abusing short-circuiting operators for control flow, and avoid the deprecated `__proto__`

Comment: @Bergi what to use instead of __proto__? Object.getPrototypeOf() ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: @Bergi isPrototypeOf could be event better i guess

Comment: What do you actually want to check? For just a primitive/object distinction the OPs `typeof obj !== "object" || obj === null` is fine (and does **not** miss `undefined`, albeit ignoring function objects, which seems sensible). If you want to include function objects, use `Object(obj) === obj`. Or do you want to check for "plain" objects, i.e. those that don't have a custom prototype like class instances?

Comment: @Bergi didn't understand about short-circuiting operators, any example and why to avoid, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12639897/1048572

Comment: @Bergi imho a bare if block you suggested is worse, matter of taste imho

Comment: Bare or not, you should use an `if` instead of `||` - while it might be a matter of taste, the taste of the huge majority is for readable code instead of exotic notation.